# DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer xxx using any of the configured protocols

Tags: windows-sbs-2008

I want to figure out why these event message is coming all the time. It comes from different computers and even the computers aren't turned on. All are connected with a SBS 2008. We have printers from HP in house and the server is a HP ProLiant ML350. Only TCP/IP is in the list for default protocols of component services.

But why is this error ocurring? How can I find it out?

Answer (score 1):

Normally the GUID of the application which is attempting to contact the remote computers is listed along with that error message. Expand `Component Services > Computers > My Computer > DCOM Config` on the SBS server and try to match the GUID from the error message with an Application ID (`View > Detail` to see the Application ID). This may assist your further investigation of the cause of your error.

Regards

Comment: Is there a way to make a search in the DCOM Config View? I made the search manually (comparing with `GUID` listed in the details tab (System -> Provider -> Guid), but I didn't found a match ...